# To sync notes of S Memo to Ubuntu?

Tags: android, sync, notes

I have the Android phone where I have notes. 
I would like to control them periodically in my Ubuntu laptop because too much work to handle them with the phone itself. 
It would be great if the phone then could sync back and understand changes on the notes in Ubuntu.

How can you notes of S Memo of Android with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Google Keep` instead. It is much more robust and scalable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Samsung allows third party-software to access the S Memo notes in your Samsung account. Samsung uses the word "synchronize" to mean "back up to our servers in case you need them on another phone".

There is a newer app called S Note (not sure if that is available to you) which does have a Windows counterpart, and lets you access the notes on another platform, presumably from within a browser.

Personally, I use Evernote for Android together with Nixnote2 for Ubuntu, which does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: I cannot find nixnote in apt-cache. How did you install it? Is there any simpler application than Evernote to communicate with any program with Ubuntu?

Comment: I installed Nixnote2 straight from Github and I admit it was a bit of a hassle. Everpad is much easier, but has fewer features. Other alternatives are discussed [here](http://itsfoss.com/5-evernote-alternatives-linux/). Then there is [Google Keep](http://itsfoss.com/install-google-keep-ubuntu-1310/) and [many others](http://www.slant.co/topics/697/~what-is-the-best-cross-platform-note-taking-app).

Answer (score 1):

I setup my S note to sync to evernote, then I can access that through ubuntu on web. And I think there's a evernote client for ubuntu, but I don't remember it.

I wish there was a web interface for S note.

Answer (score 1):

You can select and share the notes with OneDrive and then access from your machine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep Samsung Notes, than you have two solutions right now:

1. Install Anbox (android emulator) than you can install samsung notes and access while using the emulator (have not tasted but should work, i would not recommend if you have not a good machine)
2. Move/sync your notes to one of online clouds (ex Google Drive, Dropbox, Evernote etc) -preferred.
   `I use this solution.`